# How to use xupload yii extension

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, yii-extensions, multifile-uploader, yii-xupload

```
I want to use upload multiple with xupload extension,
but didn't work my code?
```

this Configuration

> **config.php**
>            'aliases' => array( //If you used composer your path should be
>                         'xupload' => 'ext.vendor.Asgaroth.xupload',
>                         //If you manually installed it
>                         'xupload' => 'ext.xupload', ),
>
> ```
>      and  the Widget in views 
>     <?php   $this->widget('xupload.XUpload', array(
>                         'url' => Yii::app()->createUrl("site/upload"),
>                         'model' => $model,
>                         'attribute' => 'file',
>                         'multiple' => true,
>     ));  ?>
>      and controller
>     class SiteController extends CController
>     {
>         public function actions()
>         {
>             return array(
>                 'upload'=>array(
>                     'class'=>'xupload.actions.XUploadAction',
>                     'path' =>Yii::app() -> getBasePath() . "/../uploads",
>                     'publicPath' => Yii::app() -> getBaseUrl() . "/uploads",
>                 ),
>             );
>         }
>     }
> ```

```
and this view my application
```

[image]

```
but don't work, please help to solve my problem,
thanks ?
```

this example: http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: possible duplicate of [yii ajax xupload form submit is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773839/yii-ajax-xupload-form-submit-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Widget cannot be nested inside a form. Move it our of the form and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Change you widget code. Use 'showForm' => false option and set id the same like your main form has 'htmlOptions' => array('id'=>'your-main-form-id',). And it will work inside your form.

```
<?php   $this->widget('xupload.XUpload', array(
                    'url' => Yii::app()->createUrl("site/upload"),
                    'htmlOptions' => array('id'=>'your-main-form-id',),
                    'model' => $model,
                    'attribute' => 'file',
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'showForm' => false,
));  ?>
```